# Dev C ++ what does "node *head=NULL;" mean;

Tags: c++, linked-list

`node *head=NULL;`

I don' undertand what does above code does?
Could you help me ? Thanks,

Comment: Please read a good C++ book and follow some tutorials, this is very basic. Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for learning the languages you're using.

Comment: In order to understant this, you need first to understand the concept of pointer. Search in internet. There are a lot of good tutorials

Comment: There is a list of good books [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here

```
node *head
```

Defines a pointer to a `node`, and calls that pointer `head`.

```
=NULL;
```

Here, `NULL` is assigned to it. According to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL), `NULL` is:

> The macro NULL is an implementation-defined null pointer constant,
>   which may be
>
> an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates
>   to zero (until C++11)
>
> an integer literal with value zero, or a prvalue of type
>   std::nullptr_t (since C++11)

In the end, the result is that `head` holds a value of `0`. This way it can be queried, for instance using `if (head == NULL){...` or something similar.

When `NULL` is assigned to a pointer, this usually signifies that it's not pointing to a valid object (yet).

Answer (score -1):

`NULL` is the macro defined for representing a pointer without a defined address. You can read more about in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL

Comment: How does this help to understand the OP question?